# Testing typescript modules without exports

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I'm working on legacy environment and I have Typescript files which contain modules or/and classes

```
class SomeClass {
    ...
}

module AndAModule {
    export namespace NestedNamespace {
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice the lack of "export" keyword in the top level modules/classes.

I would like to test functions in the "NestedNamespace" using Jest library. However when I import the Typescript file in a test file:

```
var service = require("/path/to/file/SomeService.ts")
```

I have no access neither to a class nor module defined in the SomeService.ts file. If add the "export" keyword before module and class I'm able to access them through the object returned from require, however this breaks whole environment and other files, as after this, the module and the class are not present in the outFile generated by typescript.

How can I import desired modules from files, without adding any export statement?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue (almost exactly 2 years later). Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work on this project anymore and I think I haven't found a solution :P

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function which is not being exported, then some other function which is exported, is calling that un-exported function. Test the exported method, and you will indirectly be testing the un-exported one.